# SQL Generated JSON is breaking in the middle with carriage return

Tags: arrays, json

I am facing a strange problem.  I am generating a JSON payload from database and it looks like below.  The problem the JSON file gets a new line character in the middle of the screen resulting into parse errors.

This is with any record. And yes, I have checked there are no special or junk characters in the incoming data.

below is how Json looks. **You will see that the last line is where string ends up with a carriage return into new line causing parsing issues.**

[image]

```
{
    "InvoiceNumber": 5121000026,
    "InvoiceCurrency": "USD",
    "InvoiceAmount": 0,
    "InvoiceDate": "2023-10-31",
    "InvoiceType": "Standard",
    "BusinessUnit": "ABCDEFG Operations",
    "Supplier": "DKOTA",
    "SupplierSite": "abcd",
    "Description": "Some description",
    "invoiceLines": [{
        "LineNumber": "1",
        "Description": "test",
        "LineAmount": "400",
        "invoiceLineProjectDff": [{
            "_PROJECT_ID_Display": "19090001",
            "_TASK_ID_Display": "003.0108200.00000",
            "_EXPENDITURE_ITEM_DATE": "2023-10-31",
            "_EXPENDITURE_TYPE_ID_Display": "Equipment",
            "_ORGANIZATION_ID_Display": "N. A. ABCDEFG Company"
        }]
    }, {
        "LineNumber": "2",
        "Description": "test",
        "LineAmount": "400",
        "invoiceLineProjectDff": [{
            "_PROJECT_ID_Display": "19090001",
            "_TASK_ID_Display": "003.0108200.00000",
            "_EXPENDITURE_ITEM_DATE": "2023-10-31",
            "_EXPENDITURE_TYPE_ID_Display": "Equipment",
            "_ORGANIZATION_ID_Display": "N. A. ABCDEFG Company"
        }]
    }, {
        "LineNumber": "3",
        "Description": "test",
        "LineAmount": "-400",
        "invoiceLineProjectDff": [{
            "_PROJECT_ID_Display": "19090001",
            "_TASK_ID_Display": "003.0108200.00000",
            "_EXPENDITURE_ITEM_DATE": "2023-10-31",
            "_EXPENDITURE_TYPE_ID_Display": "Equipment",
            "_ORGANIZATION_ID_Display": "N. A. ABCDEFG Company"
        }]
    }, {
        "LineNumber": "4",
        "Description": "test",
        "LineAmount": "-400",
        "invoiceLineProjectDff": [{
            "_PROJECT_ID_Display": "19090001",
            "_TASK_ID_Display": "003.0108200.00000",
            "_EXPENDITURE_ITEM_DATE": "2023-10-31",
            "_EXPENDITURE_TYPE_ID_Display": "Equipment",
            "_ORGANIZATION_ID_Display": "N. A. 
            ABCDEFG Company "
        }]
    }]
}
```

below is the code snippet that generates above json

```
 FOR i IN gethdrrec LOOP
        -- Create JSON payload
        
            l_json.put('InvoiceNumber',i.document_id);
            l_json.put('InvoiceCurrency','USD');
            l_json.put('InvoiceAmount',i.amount);
            l_json.put('InvoiceDate', i.trx_date);
            l_json.put('InvoiceType', i.invoice_type);
            l_json.put('BusinessUnit', 'ABCDEFG Operations and Support (US)');
            l_json.put('Supplier', 'DKOTA');
            l_json.put('SupplierSite','abcd');
            l_json.put('Description', 'Some description');
            
           FOR j IN getlnrec(i.document_id) LOOP
           
           l_children.append(json_object_t('
             {  
                         
                "LineNumber": "'||j.line_id||'",
                "Description": "'||j.description||'",
                "LineAmount": "'||j.line_value||'",
                 "invoiceLineProjectDff":[{
                     "_PROJECT_ID_Display": "'||j.project_code||'",
                     "_TASK_ID_Display": "'||j.project_sub_code||'",
                     "_EXPENDITURE_ITEM_DATE": "'||i.trx_date||'",
                     "_EXPENDITURE_TYPE_ID_Display": "'||j.expenditure_type||'",
                     "_ORGANIZATION_ID_Display": "N. A. ABCDEFG Company"
                  }]
            }'
            )
            );
            
            END LOOP;
            
    END LOOP;
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Thank you ,
Darsh